# ansible : how export error log, when task is failed?

Tags: ansible

FACTS:
When task is failed : Ansible stops playbook.
OK, So only way how can I work with this output error log ( export to some file... )  is enable ignore_errors ?
Because for me would be better if I can keep this task as failed, to see that here is some error.

In ansible debug I see : stderr: "date: unrecognized option '--bad-option'
But I cant export it anywhere during the play right ?

```
---
- hosts: all

  tasks:

  - name: Patching
    #example command with wrong options to generate error
    command: date --bad-option
    register: patch_output

  - name: Debug Patching
    debug:
      msg: patch_output.stdout

  - name: export
    local_action: copy content="{{ patch_output.stdout }}" dest="{{ inventory_hostname }}.log"
```

Ansible output:

```
PLAY *********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host01]

TASK [Patching] **********************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [host01]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["date", "--bad-option"], "delta": "0:00:00.009541", "end": "2023-03-11 16:12:42.709872", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2023-03-11 16:12:42.700331", "stderr": "date: unrecognized option '--bad-option'\nTry `date --help' for more information.", "stderr_lines": ["date: unrecognized option '--bad-option'", "Try `date --help' for more information."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************
host01 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: is the result variable registered somewhere? You might use patch_output instead.

Comment: Not sure what you mean,  result is registered here:  `register: patch_output`

Comment: Then it should be `register: result` and not `register: patch_output`.

Comment: Aah, you have right... But still not helped. Error output not exported.

Comment: failed_when helps you to make the task fail if the condition is met. Please edit your question and add a reproducible example and the expected result.

Comment: OK I rewritten it ...I think that main reason is that next tasks are not processing, so I cant do nothing here, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: ***"I can't export it (stderr) anywhere during the play right?"***

A: No. You can. Use [*block/rescue*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#blocks). Quote:

> If any tasks in the block return failed, the rescue section executes tasks to recover from the error ... Ansible provides a couple of variables for tasks in the rescue portion of a block:

- ansible_failed_task: The task that returned ‘failed’ and triggered the rescue. For example, to get the name use *ansible_failed_task.name*.
- ansible_failed_result: The captured return result of the failed task that triggered the rescue. This would equate to having used this var in the register keyword.

For example, the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - block:

        - command: date --bad-option
          register: patch_output

      rescue:

        - debug:
            msg: |
              ansible_failed_task:
                {{ ansible_failed_task|to_yaml|indent(2) }}
              ansible_failed_result:
                {{ ansible_failed_result|to_yaml|indent(2) }}
          when: debug|d(false)|bool

        - name: Write to logfile
          lineinfile:
            dest: /tmp/ansible.log
            line: >-
              {{ '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'|strftime }} [ERR]
              {{ ansible_failed_task.action }}:
              {{ ansible_failed_result.stderr_lines|join('; ') }}
          delegate_to: localhost
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=true 
  cmd:
  - date
  - --bad-option
  delta: '0:00:00.008171'
  end: '2023-03-11 18:40:01.379714'
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 1
  start: '2023-03-11 18:40:01.371543'
  stderr: |-
    date: unrecognized option '--bad-option'
    Try 'date --help' for more information.
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Write to logfile] **********************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=1    ignored=0
```

---

and writes the log

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/ansible.log 
2023-03-11 18:40:01 [ERR] command: date: unrecognized option '--bad-option'; Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

Enable debug if you want to display all  details

```bash
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e debug=true
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Ansible stops executing a play as soon as a task fails. However, you can use `failed_when` and set it to `false` to treat specific errors as non-fatal, allowing the play to continue execution and use the registered variable. Note that I have added the `changed_when: false` to help Ansible a bit because by default Ansible will return as changed and the command `date` will not really change anything on the remote host but you can manipulate it according to your need.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Patching
    #example command with wrong options to generate error
      command: date --bad-option
      failed_when: false
      changed_when: false
      register: patch_output

    - name: Debug Patching
      debug:
        msg: "{{ patch_output.stderr }}"

    - name: export
      local_action: copy content="{{ patch_output.stdout }}" dest="{{ inventory_hostname }}.log"
      when: patch_output.rc == 0
```

Gives:

```
TASK [Patching] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Debug Patching] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "date: unrecognized option '--bad-option'\nTry 'date --help' for more information."
}

TASK [export] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]
```

Comment: OK, I tested and works... looks that it works also just with this line `failed_when: false`
Anyway, I am little confused how this condition works : `failed_when: false`
So.. normally this task is failed right ? and with this condition  : `failed_when: false`  it is changed to `not failed` or ?
And why we need there also `changed_when: false` ?

Comment: `failed_when: false`means that a task will not fail even if there are errors or failures encountered during the execution and it will still continue running and will not stop the playbook from completing. I  have updated my answer.